# What is wrong with this jQuery, showing/hiding text depending on checkbox value?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am puzzled as to why this doesn't do what I expect - it seems so obvious. Thanks in advance.

```
if ($(':checkbox').is(":checked")) {
    $('p').show();
} else {
    $('p').hide();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Guz4D/

Comment: Does it need a click listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap you code inside an event listener

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

 $('#checkboxID').click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('p').show();
            }
            else{
                $('p').hide();
            }
        });
 });
```

Comment: checkbox is not the id, so your answer is not working

Comment: i am giving as an example. you can replace it with the id of the checkbox or class.

Comment: Please post the answer or write as you can achieve.. in place of `checkbox write checkboxID`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
   $("#red").click(function(){
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#pp').show();
     } else {
     $('#pp').hide();
     }
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Guz4D/2/)